# Exchange 2010 disable authentication to distribution groups by default

Tags: exchange-2010, powershell, distribution-lists

I know this is against best practices, but I have been unable to find a way to make this the default setting when creating new distribution groups on Exchange 2010.  I know how to do it from EMS and powershell for individual groups (or run a script to change all), but I'd like it to do it by default when initially created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Barring any 3rd party tools from the likes of Quest or others, this isn't possible with the built-in Exchange tools.

You can't set a default like this on new distribution groups.  Exchange simply doesn't allow you to setup "defaults" for future new objects.

Your best option would be to simply use PS cmdlets when creating the new distro groups to specify that it will allow for non-authenticated senders to send to it.

Use the `-RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled $false`  to do so (which you already know it would seem).